# How to add weight of edges when calculate personallization Page Rank

Tags: python, networkx, pagerank

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/_modules/networkx/algorithms/link_analysis/pagerank_alg.html

I want to calculate weighted personalized page rank. How should I implement with specific start node?
Code:

```
import newtworkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
[G.add_node(k) for k in [1,2,3,4]]
G.add_edge(2,1)
G.add_edge(3,1)
G.add_edge(4,1)
ppr1 = nx.pagerank(G,personalization={1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1})
```

How to set the nstart and personalization ? Thanks!

Comment: Hi maybe you could add more detail to your question.

Comment: for example, (2, 1, 1.0) (3, 1, 2.0) 1.0 and 2.0 are their weights of edges. from node 2 to 1, the weight of the edge is 1.0. From node 3 to 1, the weight of edge is 2.0

Comment: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pagerank.js) Weighted PageRank

Comment: You are very welcome, however: An "upvote" is usually a better way to say thank you than a "thank you" comment. Also: Now you know, how about sharing it with the community? You can simply add an answer to your own question to do that.

Comment: hi, I think my result is wrong:(( I use G.add_weighted_edges_from([(0,1,3.0),(1,2,7.5)]) to add weights. But I do not know it is correct or not.

Comment: And do you know how to set nstart?

Comment: Fixed code indent.

Comment: You mean my code there or ?